# Is there something that keeps PubCenter ads from showing in unpublished app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using AdRotator in my WP8 app, and while the NAX and AdDuplex ads display just fine, PubCenter ads are not displaying.  Does the app have to be published for them to display now?  I've done this before, but not since the latest AdRotator update, and thefore probably not the latest PubCenter update.

Here's my xaml:

```
<AdRotator:AdRotatorControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="Ad1"
        Visibility="Visible"
        Height="80"
        Width="480"
        DefaultAdType="PubCenter"
        PubCenterAppId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        PubCenterAdUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
        AdDuplexAppId="xxxxxxx"
        InneractiveAppId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        DefaultSettingsFileUri="xxxxxxxx/defaultAdSettings.xml"
        SettingsUrl="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml"
        Margin="0" />
```

Like I said, the other ads show just fine, both in device and emulator, but the PubCenter ads don't show.  The only thing I can think of is that they don't work in unpublished apps now, but I don't want to publish without them working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  PubCenter ads require more capabilities than the NAX ads.  PubCenter ads require:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO"/>
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
```

I really hate that it requires user identity and photo library, as I see no real reason for them to be there, and it makes the app look more suspicious, IMO, but there they are....